# GPU Rendering but it appears CPU is being used

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

I chose my nvidia graphics card under computing device in user settings and saved the settings but when I render and check my task manager almost all my cpu is being used by blender. What is going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enable GPU rendering in the properties panel. 
[image]

Also, make sure you're using cycles, **not** blender internal.

[image]